# Alternative Solution for Pritty Print Codes on Webstie

Tags: javascript

I am working on a website that users can write HTML, CSS and JavaScript codes in a online code editor. The editor can highlight and pritty-print the code if user click the relative buttons. Lately, I've  implemented those features by means of Highlight.js and Pritter.js. After I completed the code. I found that those two libaray are very large, especially Pritter.js, which takes up 753KB after parsed by webpack, and still requires 218.96KB after being gziped. It has significantly slowed down the page loading and wrosen users' experience. So, my question is, what I should do to reduce the bundle size and boost up the loading speed?

P.S. I think Pritter.js doesn't meant to be used in production, instead, it is a development tool for developers. Originally it runs on Node.js environment, and the version I used is a simple "browserify" version without enough optimizations.

Comment: You can defer the loading of prettier script i.e. lazy load it. Are you using any framework or just plain JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [prism.js](https://prismjs.com/). There you can decide what type of features and languages support do you need.